# Having trouble getting usable results from Watson's Document Conversion service

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, document-conversion

When I try to convert this document

https://public.dhe.ibm.com/common/ssi/ecm/po/en/poq12347usen/POQ12347USEN.PDF

with Watson's Document Conversion service, all I get is four answer units, one for each level-4 heading.  What I really need is 47 answer units, one for each FAQ question.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often a custom configuration can be used to produce more usable results in the case of a document such as this one.
The custom configuration can be passed to Document Conversion in a config form part on the request.

Please refer to the documentation (https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/document-conversion/customizing.shtml)
for more details on the options available.  In this particular case, the following seems to give improved results:

```
{
  "conversion_target": "ANSWER_UNITS",
  "pdf": {
    "heading": {
      "fonts": [
        {"level": 1, "min_size": 14, "max_size": 80},
        {"level": 2, "min_size": 11, "max_size": 12, "bold": true},
        {"level": 3, "min_size": 9, "max_size": 11, "bold": true}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```